# How do I remove an element from the vector?

Tags: c++

So I have to write my own method.

I did  the following:

```
vector<float> remove(vector<float>& sortedVector, float input)
{

    for (vector<float>::iterator it = sortedVector.begin() ; it != sortedVector.end(); ++it)
    {
        if(input == *it)
        {
            sortedVector.erase(it);
        }
    }

    return sortedVector;
}
```

However compiler breaks at for loop. Where did I go wrong? I need to return the modified vector after the given value of the user is removed from the vector.

[Output of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOhMf.jpg)

Comment: instead of making your own function just use the [erase and remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom)

Comment: @NathanOliver Because he says "i have to write my own method", this is probably for a course or something.

Comment: The compiler breaks? What compiler are you using that suffers an _internal error_ with something this simple?

Comment: After `erase(it)` the iterator is invalid and `++it` is undefined.

Comment: Returning a copy of a vector passed into the function by reference? That cannot be right.

Comment: @ChristianHackl fairly new to both vector and by reference. I need to remove an element user wants to remove then update the original vector.

Comment: @Bayazid Seriously, if you showed up at a job interview with your own function to erase from a vector, it would not be looked upon highly by the interviewer.  Who is teaching your class?

Answer (score 0):

Why make your own function? You can simply do this:

```
vector.erase(std::remove(vector.begin(), vector.end(), item_to_delete ), vector.end());
```

Comment: I'm required to write my own function.

Comment: @Bayazid Your requirements didn't state you had to write a `for` loop, only that you had to write a function.  That function could have inside of it the call to `erase / remove`.

Comment: exactly.. you can wrap my code in you function and that's it.. and if you prefer something more verbose - check the actual implementation of these algorithms to devise your own version.

Comment: *"I have to write my own method"* is synonymous for *"cannot use a library"*. Providing a solution that wraps a library call in a function does not meet that requirement. You cannot possibly be **this** dense. Suggesting to study the implementation (likely incomprehensible, even to somewhat experienced developers) is like saying RTFM. -1 for the undue arrogance alone.

Comment: "I have to write my own method" is NOT synonymous for "cannot use a library".